# Not Getting Jasper Report Within Specified Date Range

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports

Is there any syntax error in this code or query because i am not getting the required report? I have created a JFrame with JDatechoosr. When i select the dates and click view report, it gives me empty report while i know there is data within the specified date range. I am using MYSQL DB and Netbeans. Kindly help me.

```
try{
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("Purchase.jrxml");
        String sql = "select * from purchase where purchase_date between "
                + "'"+DateChooser_frm.getDate().toString()+"' and'"+DateChooser_to.getDate().toString()+"'";
        JRDesignQuery query = new JRDesignQuery();
        query.setText(sql);
        jd.setQuery(query);
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);
    }
    catch(JRException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Print your `sql` command, then call it manually from command line MySql command. You will see if it does what you would expect. Thus you will find if it is Java problem or invalid SQL command problem.

Comment: @Honza Zidek I am suspecting it is something with the default date format of mysql. because i have another query which fetches and show the report of a specified voucher number and it is working good.

Comment: Exactly! So doesn't it work from MYSQL command-line utility? I would think the same! So then it is not a Java-related but rather an SQL-related question and you should remove all the Java code from your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first take into consideration that Mysql's default date format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. So if you are not giving the dates in this format, you will not get anything from the database. First set your date formats to match the mysql's format and then try to execute the query. You can use 'SimpleDateFormat' to do this.